# AgoraRtcEngineDelegate does not get invoked

Tags: agora.io

when I invoke AgoraRtcEngineKit.shareEngine(withAppId: "", delegate: delegate), I found none of the methods in the delegate get invoked, is there anything need to pay attention?

Answer (score 0):

None of the delegate methods should fire until you attempt to join a channel.

[This example](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-iOS-SwiftPM/tree/main/Agora_SDK-Example) is super minimal, but the delegate method still works fine. Try comparing your project's setup with that one.

Comment: I am doing exactly the same thing, and I can receive join success call back, but none of the local nor remote user joint method in the delegate is called, really odd